# some text below fraction

Tags: fractions

I am trying to place some text below the fraction but I am getting the following error:

> ! Missing $ inserted.
>   
>   $
>   l.5 ...ac{1}{\alpha_{ideal}}}*{\text{\leq r*{i-1}}
>   }$

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\underbrace{\frac{1}{\alpha_{ideal}}}_{\text{\leq r_{i-1}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Remove `\text`: what under the brace is *not* text. And add one for `ideal`: I suppose you don't mean the product of the 5 variables `i, d, e, a, l`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ \underbrace{\frac{1}{\alpha_\text{ideal}}}_{\leq r_{i-1}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]